# Как отменить изменение первого столбца в Google Table?

Tags: java, google-spreadsheet

Изменяю значения строки по названию столбца:

```
row = listFeed.getEntries().get(2);

        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("CreditC", "2000");
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("DebC", "2000");
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("CreditAeroC", "2000");
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("CardNo", "0001");
```

В моей таблице CardNo - название столбца (клетка А1) со значением 0001

После работы с нужными клетками строки, первая клетка строки (А4) изменяет свое значение на 1, вместо старого 0001.

Подскажите, как можно исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 1):

`Формат - Числа - Обычный текст` так?

Ну или

`Формат - Числа - Другие форматы - Другие форматы чисел` указать 0000

Comment: с помощью API задать форматирование пока (последний коммент Nov 11, 2015) нельзя https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=37

Comment: я в таблице задал параметр Обычный текст и при форматировании "вручную" все остается как есть. Пришлось использовать костыль и формировать строку как ".0000" - в таком случае все сохраняется, но все же хотелось бы делать без каких либо костылей